# ng-repeat not showing me value from the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat directive but it does not showing me value. Here is my code

JS File:

```
var artist = angular.module('artistApp',[]);
artist.controller('artistController',['$scope',function($scope){
$scope.author = 
{
    "name":"Barot Bellingham",
    "shortname":"Barot_Bellingham"
},
{
    "name":"Jonathan G. Ferrar II",
    "shortname":"Jonathan_Ferrar"
},
{
    "name":"Hillary Hewitt Goldwynn-Post",
    "shortname":"Hillary_Goldwynn"
}
}]);
```

HTML file:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular Demo</title>
    <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="artistController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in author">
                {{item.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Where is the mistake that i m doing wrong here.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Where are you bootstrapping/loading the module to the page? Also, see @Austin's answer regarding an syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the opening bracket to the author array

```
$scope.author = 
{
```

Needs to be:

```
$scope.author = 
[{
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last **'}**' with **']'**

Working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/bPS4BC1MkphnYJpVfbXB?p=preview)

Corrected JSON:

> [{
>           "name":"Barot Bellingham",
>           "shortname":"Barot_Bellingham"
>       },
>       {
>           "name":"Jonathan G. Ferrar II",
>           "shortname":"Jonathan_Ferrar"
>       },
>       {
>           "name":"Hillary Hewitt Goldwynn-Post",
>           "shortname":"Hillary_Goldwynn"
>       }
>       ]

Answer (score 0):

**in JS**

```
$scope.author = 
[{
    "name":"Barot Bellingham",
    "shortname":"Barot_Bellingham"
},
{
    "name":"Jonathan G. Ferrar II",
    "shortname":"Jonathan_Ferrar"
},
{
    "name":"Hillary Hewitt Goldwynn-Post",
    "shortname":"Hillary_Goldwynn"
}];
```

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in author track by $index">
    {{item.name}}
</li>
```